# Setting relationship in Model class does not create db table entries in playFramework

Tags: mysql, playframework, model, relationship

I create 3 model classes in playframework, and set one-one relationship and one-to many relationship in one of the class. The code snippet are as follows:

```
  Person.java
  ///////////////////////
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "person")
  public class Person extends Model{

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String lastName;
  private String firstName;
  private String userId;
  private Address address;
  private List<Task> tasks;

  ....
  }

  Task.java
  //////////////////////////
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "task")
  public class Task extends Model{

   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private String descript;
   private String details;

   ...........
   }

   Address.java
   ////////////////////
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "address")
   public class Address extends Model{

   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String street;
   private String state;

   .........

   }
```

I create person object and set the attributes/one-one/one-many relationships.
I try to save the person object with both attributes and relationships to mysql db by calling person.save().However, it ends up saving only attributes userId/firstName/LastName. the address object and tasks list object are not saved in db. 
My question is : is there any way to save the relationship objects in db long with person.save()? that is , after calling person.save(), address table and task table create new entires corresponding to them. 
I end up setting foreign keys in person class to handle this relationship manually.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's actually a JPA question. You might want to add the JPA tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at a JPA tutorial in particular topics about `@OneToMany` and `@OneToOne` annotations. I'd recommend https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne.